# Retrieve pinout of proximity sensor

Tags: output, proximity-sensor, pinout

I need to retrieve the pinout of a proximity sensor. I don't have any specification nor order code.

The sensor has 3 wires that are connected to the main board.
I made some measurements with a multimeter and got the follow:

```
Negative probe Pin 1, Positive probe Pin 2: +12 V regardless the sensor's state
Negative probe Pin 3, Positive probe Pin 2: +12 V when idle, 0 V when active
```

It's pretty clear that Pin 1 and 2 is the input power supply (12 V) and pin 3 and 2 is the output (active low).

What I don't understand is the output configuration.
I was expecting to have a common pin (0 V or GND), one for power supply and one for the output - both referred to the same common pin.

Instead, to get consistent readings I had to move the negative probe between pin 1 (supply) and 3 (output).

The only idea that comes to mind is that a pnp bjt was placed between output and +12V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZmwiX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is I should read 0 V when idle and 12 V when active between Pin 1 and Pin 3 as well. Instead between those pins I always read something about 0 V.

Please note that the measurements were made with the sensor connected to its main board, so it's  correctly connected.

Comment: What is the reason you are considering using something that is unsupported in documentation, reliability, quality and performance?

Comment: @Andyaka, because my customer asked me to develop a new board that must support that sensor. I'm trying to understand if it's possible or not.

Comment: Then lean on your customer to supply the specifications of the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

It's a proximity sensor with 'NC' output.

[image]

While not sensing, the output transistor would be cut off and the output would be +12 V.

While sensing, the output transistor would be turned on and the output would be 0 V.

Comment: That's the answer I gave a few hours ago.  It turns out not to be the case, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @JRE, I wonder why since this configuration would  give the same multimeter readings as with the specimen.